# mysql Records not being selected in queries

Tags: mysql

So i am running some scripts to deal with an issue of duplicate records.
I am doing this in stages of how strict a match is required to be.

What i noticed was i was combining less records than i was able to identify.

The script i used to identify duplicate records is as followed

```
SELECT p.firstname, p.surname, p.email, REPLACE(p.mobile, ' ', ''), count(*) as `duplicates`
FROM person p
WHERE (p.firstname!='' and p.firstname != '?' and p.firstname != '*')
AND (p.surname!='' and p.surname != '?' and p.surname != '*' )
AND (p.email != 'xxxxx' OR p.mobile != 'xxxxx')
GROUP BY p.firstname, p.surname, p.email, p.mobile
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

so this tells me of duplicated records in which an exact match is found for the first name, surname, and either and email or a mobile number.

I then iterate through each of these and combine the records, and remove the older one.

After i ran through this, i noticed i still had a number of duplicated left over, so i attempted to select some of these.

```
SELECT p.person_id, p.firstname, p.surname, p.email, REPLACE(p.mobile, ' ', '') `p.mobile`
FROM person p
WHERE p.firstname='Ross' AND p.surname='Allen' and p.email='xxxxx'
ORDER BY p.person_id
```

This query yields the following result

[image: xxxxx]

> > (apologies but due to confidentiality i have to sensor the image, but you will have to take my word that person_id 4510 and person_id 5035 have the same mobile number)

Now the actual query that fetches these duplicate records gets its values from a result set of the query previous. Now if i enter in the mobile number as well. i get 0 results. (i have double checks, tripple checked and quadribble checked that the phone numbers are in fact exactly the same in both records given they are varchar fields.

[image]

Anyone have any idea whats going on here?

```
some table details:
Engine: InnoDB
Row format: Compact
Table rows: 42,538
Coalation:" utf8_general_ci
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the mobile number has a leading or trailing space.  In your query identifying duplicates, you remove spaces from the mobile number.  You could try changing your where clause to this:

```
WHERE p.firstname = 'Ross' AND p.surname = 'Allen' AND p.email = 'xxxxx' 
      AND REPLACE(p.mobile, ' ', '') = '[MOBILENUMBER]'
```

Comment: yeah i feel like an idiot now. :) you answer is correct. Thanks alot!

Comment: No problem.  Extra spaces can be troublesome and hard to spot some times.